# Why does starting an asyncio event loop in another thread mess with my pipe?

Tags: python, subprocess, python-asyncio

I have 2 processes. I would like `write.py` to write a message to `read.py` through a Linux pipe.

```py
### write.py
import subprocess
import asyncio
from threading import Thread

# !-- Offending code here. --!
# loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
# def side_thread(loop):
#     asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
#     loop.run_forever()
# thread = Thread(target=side_thread, args=(loop,))
# thread.start()

notify_proc = subprocess.Popen("python read.py".split(), stdin=subprocess.PIPE)

notify_proc.stdin.write("hello\n".encode("utf-8"))
```

```py
### read.py
import sys

for line in sys.stdin:
  print("Got something!")
  print(line)
```

As given, when I run `python write.py`, I get the expected output:

```
Got something!
hello
```

But when I uncomment the offending code, I don't get any output. Why?

- *Python 3.9.7*
- *Linux 5.4.72-microsoft-standard-WSL2 x86_64*

Answer (score 0):

Your buffer won't get sent over until the buffer is flushed or the process ends, and the process will not end as long as a non-daemon thread is running.  In the short term, you can add `notify_proc.stdin.flush()`, but your mixing of multiprocessing, threading and asyncio is going to lead to tears.  What on earth are you trying to do here?